# LINQ pad is showing SUM at end of result

Tags: linq, linqpad

When i run the below query by LINQ PAD then saw it was showing sum at the end of result. here is the full code and it is working.

```
void Main()
{
    var csvlines = File.ReadAllLines(@"M:\smdr(backup08-06-2015).csv");
var csvLinesData = csvlines.Skip(1).Select(l => l.Split(',').ToArray());

// i am assuming that line[7] is the Party1Name Column
// now you have a (sorted) group with n "members" (ACC, Sales, ..., n )
var groupOfUser = from line in csvLinesData 
                  where  !line[12].Contains("VM") && !line[12].Contains("Voice Mail")
                  group line by line[12] into newGroup 
                  orderby newGroup.Key 
                  select newGroup;

// The Key of your userOfGrp is the Name e.g. "ACC"
// i am assuming that x[4] is the direction Column
// I count all I or O and put them into the new User
var user = (from userOfGrp in groupOfUser
            select
                new User()
                    {
                        CSRName = userOfGrp.Key,
                        Incomming = userOfGrp.Count(x => x[4] == "I"),
                        Outgoing = userOfGrp.Count(x => x[4] == "O")
                    }).ToList();
                    user.Dump();
}

class User
{
    public string CSRName;
    public int Outgoing;
    public int Incomming;
    public int calltransfer;
}
```

i just like to know is it feature of linq pad which always show sum at end when field type is numeric ?  or something is there in my linq query which showing sum.

i am asking because just started to use linq. thanks

my screen shot attached.i also put arrow in image to indicate which area i am talking about.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "sum"? Can you include a screenshot?

Comment: That's pretty easy for you to test yourself - just make a trivial query that returns a numeric and see if the Sum is there too.

Comment: i post the screen shot. plzz see and answer. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQad will return results in its Results tab, any enumeration will have at the top of its blue box something like:

```
IEnumerable<EventLogEntry> (114 items)
```

Depending on the exact type. That count at the end is a LINQPad feature when it serializes the data for display, and it is the count not the sum.

EDIT: Now I can see a picture of the results you are talking about something different, yes that is also a LINQPad feature (and the sum).

Comment: u said linq pad show count at end of result but in my case it show the sum of data at end why ? why sum is showing in my case instead of count?

Comment: Actually, it is sum and not count. (You can check the second screenshot on http://www.linqpad.net/ )

Answer (score 0):

It is a feature of LINQPad, not of LINQ.

You can see the same feature on SQL queries in LINQPad.